# Access ref using withRouter of react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using React 14 and react-router 2.4.

I have a parent class like this

```
class Parent {

  parentMethod() {
    this.refs.child.childMethod();
  }

   render() {
     <Child ref="child" />
   }

}
```

My Child is like this

```
var {withRouter} = require('react-router');

class Child {

  childMethod() {
    alert('child method');
  }

  render() {
    <div> Child </div>
  }

}

module.exports = withRouter(Child);
```

Ealier I was using without `withRouter`. Then I was able to use the childMethod.

Now I started using it because I need the functionality of `setRouteLeaveHook`. But after using `withRouter` I am not able to use `this.refs.child.childMethod()` inside the parent.

I know that using childMethod inside Parent is not recommended but I need that use case.

How to access ChildMethod from Parent after using `withRouter` of react-router.

Comment: Not sure if this will be the answer as it's a bit hard to see what's going on here but have you tried using the ref callback method? So instead of doing `<Child ref="child" />` do `<Child ref={ function(child) { this.child = child }.bind(this) } />`. Then access it using `this.child` instead of `this.refs.child`.

Comment: @garrettmaring Yes I have tried that. That isn't working too.